# Problema con JButtton borrar

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Buenas tengo este código para **borrar** que forma parte de una clase que maneja los eventos de un **frame**:

```
if(e.getSource()== estAdmin.getSubmenu_Eliminar()){
        int Option= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(estAdmin, "Esta seguro"
                + "de que desea borrar este contacto", "Borrar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if(Option== 0){    
            int fila= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getSelectedRow();

            String id= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();

            estDAO.borrar(Integer.parseInt(id));
            this.ListarTabla(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante());
        }
    }
```

El siguiente es el método al que le envía el parámetro que obtiene:

```
public void borrar(int Id) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;

        try {
            con = dbcon.conectar();

        String sql= "DELETE FROM notas WHERE id=?";
            pstm= con.prepareStatement(sql);

            pstm.setInt(1, Id);

            pstm.execute();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectar a la BD");
    }
    finally {
        dbcon.desconectar(con);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el programa e intentar borrar un elemento del **JTable** obtengo el siguiente **stackTrace**:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "David"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at comm.estudiante.dao.controlador.ControladorEstudiante.actionPerformed(ControladorEstudiante.java:192)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

La línea 192 que menciona el **stackTrace** es la siguiente:

```
estDAO.borrar(Integer.parseInt(id));
```

Pueden decirme porque me ocurre este error, cuando veo el stackTrace lo que me dice es como si el método no estuviera recibiendo el numero de la columna.

Este es el **DefaultTableModel** del JTable:

```
public void ListarTabla(JTable tabla){
    DefaultTableModel modeloTabla= new DefaultTableModel();
    tabla.setModel(modeloTabla);

    modeloTabla.addColumn("NOMBRE");
    modeloTabla.addColumn("MATRICULA");
    modeloTabla.addColumn("NOTA");

    Object[] columna= new Object[3];

    //instancia del List
    int objGuardados= estDAO.extraerTodos().size();

    for (int i = 0; i < objGuardados; i++) {
        columna[0]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getNombre();
        columna[1]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getMatricula();
        columna[2]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getNota();

        modeloTabla.addRow(columna);
    }

}
```

El siguiente código corresponde al **List** del que se llena la tabla:

```
public List<Estudiante> extraerTodos() {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmnt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM notas";
    List<Estudiante> lista = new ArrayList<>();    

    try {
        con = dbcon.conectar();
        stmnt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
        lista.add(new Estudiante(
                rs.getInt("id"),
                rs.getString("nombre"),
                rs.getString("matricula"),
                rs.getInt("nota")
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Al parecer hay un error al convertir el string a int, para saber que obtienes imprimes la variable string, y verifica que realmente el string sea un entero

Comment: Me dice que es valor de la variable es `gk`, un valor de prueba que había introducido, pero no entiendo, con este código se obtiene el índice del objeto `String id= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();`, como puedo hacer para convertir realmente a **int**, porque siempre lo he hecho con `Integer.parseInt(nombreVariable)`

Comment: Si lo que intentas es convertir el valor gk que contiene el string es por eso que te arroja la excepción, porque no gk no es un entero, o tal vez estoy entiendo mal tu comentario!!1

Comment: Seleccioné **gk** para hacer una prueba, del método `borrar(int id)`, selecciono otro objeto y me da el mismo error pero con el nombre de ese objeto, por ejemplo: **David**, me esta devolviendo el ***String* del nombre del objeto, no un toString**, no se que sucede

Comment: Tal vez sea que estas obteniendo la columna nombre en vez de la columna que almacena el id, la posición 0 indica que columna quieres obtener de la fila seleccionada, como tienes estructurada tu JTable

Comment: Pero no hay mas posiciones en el JTable, como hago para conseguir el **id** del objeto que selecciono y a partir de ahí pasárselo al método `borrar (int id)`

Comment: Como rellenas la tabla?, usas un vector, un List obviamente con los objetos de cada registro de BD, o que tipo de estructura ocupas?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45178/discussion-between-david-and-oscarsolis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías hacer lo siguiente y apoyarte del vector que ocupas :

```
     if(e.getSource()== estAdmin.getSubmenu_Eliminar()){
                int Option= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(estAdmin, "Esta seguro"
                        + "de que desea borrar este contacto", "Borrar", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if(Option== 0){    
                    //obtenemos la posicion de la arreglo del cual extraeremos el id a ocupar
                    int fila= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getSelectedRow();

           List<Estudiante> estudiantes = estDAO.extraerTodos();
           Estudiante e = estudiantes.get(fila); 
           int id = e.getID();



     estDAO.borrar(id);
                this.ListarTabla(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @oscarsolis, puedes entrar a la conversación abierta mas arriba, quisiera hacerte solo una pregunta sobre el código que me has enviado

Comment: estoy en el chat, hay podemos conversar!

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas tu mensaje de error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "David" at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Puedes ver que el problema es causado al tratar de parsear un String que no tiene valor numerico a entero, en este caso el valor de id es "David" , este valor deberia ser un valor numerico:

```
estDAO.borrar(Integer.parseInt(id));
```

Asegura que el valor de `id` siempre contenga un String con valor numerico.

Comment: Tienes razón, es cierto, puedes darme por favor un ejemplo de como puedo obtener el id del objeto para proceder a borrarlo de la base datos

Comment: Agrega tu objeto Estudiante y como lo llenas , me parece que en lugar de agregar el valor de id agregas el nombre lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias